# Solve Radiation Total Energy Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have a system that I assumed is lumped (perfect conduction) with heat transfer only through radiation with source $A$. The equation is as follows

$$C \frac{dT}{dt} = A - BT^4$$

$A = 13.876$ ,

$B = 6.334\cdot 10^{-10}$

$C = 138.362$

How would I go about solving this? I know that $T(t=0) = 298.15 K$, and I want to solve for the time when $T = 313.15 K$ (here, $K$ = Kelvin). Numerical solutions are okay.

Comment: Do you need an analytical solution, or is an approximate answer sufficient?

Comment: @MattiP.if by approximate you mean numerically, yes that is fine.

Comment: I would recommend a small computer code that would iteratively solve the problem. You could use Euler's method, Runge-Kutta etc ...

Comment: I think the fourth order term will cause some problems. $298.15^4$ is already a large number ... What are the values of $C, A$ and $B$?

Comment: @MattiP.B has boltzmanns constant as well as a factor of 0.002 which helps.

Comment: If you don't want to code, Wolfram Alpha can also help you:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Runge-Kutta+method,+dy%2Fdx+%3D+45-(1.3806e-23)*y%5E4,+y(0)+%3D+298.15,+from+0+to+2,+h+%3D+.01

Comment: I didn't understand the values of $C, A$ and $B$, but you can type them in manually. Just enter something like this to Wolfram Alpha:
Runge-Kutta method, dy/dx = 45-(1.3806e-23)*y^4, y(0) = 298.15, from 0 to 2, h = .01

Comment: Why can't you solve it analytically \begin{align} \frac{dT}{A-BT^{4}} &= \frac{dt}{C} \\ \implies \frac{dT}{(\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}T^{2})(\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}T^{2})} &= \frac{dt}{C} \\ \implies \frac{1}{2\sqrt{A}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}T^{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}T^{2}} \right)dT &= \frac{dt}{C} \\ \implies \dots \end{align}

Comment: @MattiP.I edited the question to add the coefficients if you would like to write an answer so I can mark it as answered. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following Python code:

```
def calculate_derivative(T):
    A = 13.876
    B = 6.334e-10
    C = 138.362
    return (A-B*T**4)/C

def RK4_update(T, dt):
    # Fourth order Runge-kutta solver
    k1 = calculate_derivative(T          )
    k2 = calculate_derivative(T + dt*k1/2)
    k3 = calculate_derivative(T + dt*k2/2)
    k4 = calculate_derivative(T + dt*k3  )

    return T + dt*(k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

def main():
    T0 = 298.15
    dt = 4.0
    for k in range(7):
        dt = dt/2
        t = 0
        T  = T0
        while T< 313.15:
            T = RK4_update(T, dt)
            t += dt
        print "dt = ", dt , "-> Answer:", t

main()
```

and it gives the following output:

```
dt =  2.0 -> Answer: 250.0
dt =  1.0 -> Answer: 250.0
dt =  0.5 -> Answer: 249.5
dt =  0.25 -> Answer: 249.25
dt =  0.125 -> Answer: 249.25
dt =  0.0625 -> Answer: 249.1875
dt =  0.03125 -> Answer: 249.1875
```

The program calculates the numerical solution with increasingly small time intervals and converges to the indicated result. Therefore, I conclude that the answer is $249.2$ seconds. If you think that there is an error in the code, or you need to tweak the constants, feel free to copy the code and play with it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

@Mattos gave the way to go $$dt=\frac{C}{2\sqrt{A}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}\,T^{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}\,T^{2}} \right)dT$$ Integrating
$$t+K=\frac{C}{2\sqrt{A}} \left( \frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{B}\, T}{\sqrt[4]{A}}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{A}\,
   \sqrt[4]{B}}+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{B}\, T}{\sqrt[4]{A}}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{A}\,
   \sqrt[4]{B}}\right)$$

Using your numbers and the condition gives $K=-3245.34$.

Now, using $T=313.15$ gives $t=249.168$.

Notice that, because of the $\tanh ^{-1}(.)$, there is an asymptote corresponding to
$$\frac{\sqrt[4]{B}\, T}{\sqrt[4]{A}}=1 \implies T_\infty=384.722$$

Below are listed some values

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
t & T \\
0 & 298.15 \\
 79.5275 & 303.15 \\
 162.420 & 308.15 \\
 249.168 & 313.15 \\
 340.368 & 318.15 \\
 436.756 & 323.15 \\
 539.255 & 328.15 \\
 649.042 & 333.15 \\
 767.656 & 338.15 \\
 897.163 & 343.15 \\
 1040.42 & 348.15 \\
 1201.55 & 353.15 \\
 1386.82 & 358.15 \\
 1606.45 & 363.15 \\
 1878.83 & 368.15 \\
 2242.53 & 373.15 \\
 2804.23 & 378.15 \\
 4195.16 & 383.15
\end{array}
\right)$$